# Getting ssl certificate issue

Tags: ssl, heroku, firewall

I have a site which is hosted using `godaddy` and `heroku` and it has issued SSL certificate fro the godaddy.

Right now I am facing issue as, I (including all my friends and family) can see site very well (It means I can see green color HTTPS on the address bar.)

But for my client getting the SSL error(red cross on HTTPS).

First I thought SSL certificate is not properly installed so I online check the SSL certificate error. For this I used following sites

https://www.sslshopper.com

https://www.digicert.com

but all the sites showing that the certificate is perfectly issued and applied.

Can any one please help me what is actual cause behind this. Is there any firewall issue. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Have you checked with [SSLLabs](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and especially looked for chain issues? If this does not help add the URL for your site because otherwise it is not possible to see what your problem really is.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you can find kotakli.bvcrewards.com

Comment: The site looks fine. Then it would be interesting what kind of error your clients get exactly ("red cross" is not a detailed error description)  and which browser (including version) on which operating system they use.

Comment: Perhaps the real website is https://www.bvcrewards.com. If this is correct, no connection is accepted on port 443, and this must be fixed.